# Loop through Gridview HeadRow's

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Is it possible to loop through all *HeaderRow Cells*?

Currently, I am doing this, which is annoying/tedious

```
gv.HeaderRow.Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
gv.HeaderRow.Cells[1].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
gv.HeaderRow.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
gv.HeaderRow.Cells[3].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
gv.HeaderRow.Cells[4].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
gv.HeaderRow.Cells[5].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
gv.HeaderRow.Cells[6].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
gv.HeaderRow.Cells[7].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
gv.HeaderRow.Cells[8].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
gv.HeaderRow.Cells[9].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
gv.HeaderRow.Cells[10].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
gv.HeaderRow.Cells[11].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
gv.HeaderRow.Cells[12].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
```

any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

```
public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
    {
        List<DailySummary> lstDailySummary = db.DailySummaries.Include(x => x.codeAC).Include(x => x.codeC).Include(x => x.codeAcy).Include(x => x.ACInfo).ToList();
        GridView gv = new GridView();

        lstDailySummary = (List<DailySummary>)Session["Paging"];

        List<ExportExcel> lstExportedExcel = new List<ExportExcel>();

        foreach(var item in lstDailySummary)
        {
            ExportExcel export = new ExportExcel();
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Acy.ToString()))
            {
                export.Acy = item.codeAcy.location;
            }
            else
            {
                export.Acy = " ";
            }

            export.AC = item.ACInfo.RNumber;
            export.ATime = item.ATime;
            export.Assignment = item.codeAC.text;
            export.County = item.codeC.county;
            export.Flight = item.Flight;
            export.FlightDay = item.FlightDay;
            export.INumber = item.INumber;
            export.Location = item.codeL.Location;
            export.RINS = item.RINS;
            export.Starts = item.Starts;
            export.Summary = item.Summary;
            export.Total = item.Total;

            lstExportedExcel.Add(export);
            gv.DataSource = lstExportedExcel.ToList();

            gv.DataBind();
        }

        gv.ID = "DailySummaryExcel";

    //protected void gv_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //{
    //    foreach (DataControlField dcf in gv.Columns)
    //    {
    //        if (dcf.HeaderText != string.Empty)
    //            dcf.HeaderStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
    //    }
    //}


        gv.HeaderRow.Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
        gv.HeaderRow.Cells[1].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
        gv.HeaderRow.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
        gv.HeaderRow.Cells[3].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
        gv.HeaderRow.Cells[4].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
        gv.HeaderRow.Cells[5].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
        gv.HeaderRow.Cells[6].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
        gv.HeaderRow.Cells[7].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
        gv.HeaderRow.Cells[8].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
        gv.HeaderRow.Cells[9].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
        gv.HeaderRow.Cells[10].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
        gv.HeaderRow.Cells[11].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
        gv.HeaderRow.Cells[12].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;

        //gv.HeaderRow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;

        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=DailySummaryExport.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        Response.Charset = "";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        gv.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

Comment: GridView is ASP.Net. Please re-tag to correct tag, so that you might get more answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why loop? In the aspx as:

```
<HeaderStyle BackColor="LightCyan" />
```

or in the code behind as:

```
gv.HeaderRow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
```

---

#### Per your comment:

Since you just need to make a style change, you can hit the GridView right before it's rendered:

```
protected void gv_PreRender( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
    foreach ( DataControlField dcf in gv.Columns ) {
        if ( dcf.HeaderText != string.Empty )
            dcf.HeaderStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
    }
}
```

And In the Gridview markup add the function as an event handler:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" OnPreRender="gv_PreRender" />
```

or programmatically:

```
    gv.PreRender += gv_PreRender ;
```

---

#### Additional info

View your GridView in the designer and select the control.

Once selected, open/look at your Properties window.  Near the top, in the icon bar of the window, you should see a Lightning icon.

If you select this the Property page will switch to the events viewer.

This lists all events associated with the selected control in the designer. It's very easy to see which events are being handled and to add new events to a control from here

Comment: yes that does work, but the color goes all the way across.. into cells that are blank..

Comment: :) we're not mind readers...that's information you should have included in your post.  I'll amend my answer.

Comment: i have updated my code with your solution in it, and the header cells did not change color

Comment: Strange...it works on my test page.  Set up a break point and check the value of HeaderText in the condition

Comment: oh - did you add the function as the event handler for `PreRender` to the gridview? : `OnPreRender="gv_PreRender"`

Comment: no, how do I do that? sorry this is my first time using gridview

Comment: how would I do that if I am using *razor*? also, I don't have a specific view for this gridview.. it is generating this table on the fly.

Comment: Programmatically: `gv.PreRender += new System.EventHandler(gv_PreRender);`

Comment: actually even simpler `gv.PreRender += gv_PreRender ;`

Comment: I have updated my question with my entire export method.. How can i add `protected void gv_PreRender( object sender, EventArgs e )` method under my `ExportToExcel` method?  Also, i don't have properties option for gridview in MVC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112539/discussion-between-fnostro-and-bville-kid).